# Getting Surveyor Coordinates into QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-survey

I am trying to add a polygon on a map using the Add Polygon Feature in QGIS. I have a diagram from the South African Surveyor General. There is no way of using the Georeferencer in QGIS in order to draw in the polygon as there are no distinguishing features to use. The SG Diagram (attached) has coordinates of the four points of the polygon. I know that I can use the Advanced Digitizing tools to enter exact coordinates. What I do not know is how to interpret the coordinates given on the SG diagram in order to add them into the advanced digitizing tool.

If I enter the coordinates given for point A, I end up in the ocean miles from where I need to be.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screen shot of the map.

Comment: HI DanVH, welcome to GIS SE. Your question is unclear, please provide more information. Otherwise it's difficult to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Pointdump & Babel. I have re-phrased my question and added an image. For some reason I could not add a second image of my QGIS desktop.

Comment: Thanks for posting the document. I tried every way I could think of, including 5 different Lo19 coordinate systems, but I didn't have any better luck than you. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Add 100,000.00 to the "Y" column and add 3,620,000.00 to the "X" Column. The X(Southing) and Y(Westing) become:

X,Y

102547.95,3625961.17

102526.68,3625955.56

102519.72,3625981.92

102540.99,3625987.55

105741.13,3634851.93

97656.4,3625153.78

The last 2 points are, I'm guessing, Control Points for Basis of Bearing.
Assigning [EPSG:22279 Cape/Lo19](https://epsg.io/22279) to the points puts them in a plausible location near the Groot Paternoster Private Nature Reserve.
[image]

[image]